# Xarray Dataarray finding line of max Value

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, python-xarray

That's my first question here, I appreciate any help!

I've got global data in a xarray Dataarray with latitude and longitude as coordinates (.25° resolution) and I would like to find the latitude for each .25° longitude element, where the value is the highest.

I've tried `data.max('lat')` but that's giving me the maximum value of the data for each longitude element, and not the latitude.

Maybe there is a solution with `data.where()`, but I haven't figured it out yet. So perhaps someone did something similar and could help me?

Many thanks in advance
V

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution:

```
def findlineofmaxes(data):
    latmaxes = data.max('lat')
    lineofmaxes = data.where(data == latmaxes, drop=True)
    return lineofmaxes
```

It's a workaround, but works for me!

I hope it's ok, to answer my own question, instead of just deleting it.